# QGIS layers shown darker under same setting

Tags: qgis, layers, symbology

I am working on some layers and changing the symbology to represent the values into 5 different colors. For this, I change the symbology to Graduated, pick a color scale, and set it to 5 intervals. I need to do the same for 10 layers. The problem that I have is that layer 1 shows bright (this is how I want them all to be shown) and layers 2 and 3 are shown darker. I am currently using the same QGIS windows to modify the symbology on them.

Layer 1
[image]

Layer 2
[image]

QGIS version: QGIS 3.22.3 'Białowieża' on Windows 10

Comment: I guess this is due to different cell sizes and the border color. Try removing the borders and check if the brightness is then still different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the grids are the same size, but some layers have way more grids than others. I believe when there are too many grids (too close to each other when zoom to layer), this makes them look darker.

I dealt with it by changing its properties on Symbology > Layer Rendering > Blending mode > (Feature) Lighten/Soft light